# how to encode this JSON reply from Food API

Tags: json, swift

I'm getting the following response from an API Call

```
Optional(<__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x6000024638d0>(
{
    name = "";
    steps =     (
                {
            equipment =             (
                                {
                    id = 404667;
                    image = "dutch-oven.jpg";
                    name = "dutch oven";
                }
            );
            ingredients =             (
                                {
                    id = 2009;
                    image = "chili-powder.jpg";
                    name = "chili powder";
                },
                                {
                    id = 19334;
                    image = "dark-brown-sugar.png";
                    name = "brown sugar";
                },
                                {
                    id = 1065062;
                    image = "whole-chicken.jpg";
                    name = meat;
                }
            );
            length =             {
                number = 15;
                unit = minutes;
            };
            number = 1;
            step = "Heat 1 package (4 cups) Savory Meat base, thawed, in a Dutch oven over medium heat. Stir in 2 teaspoons chili powder and 1 teaspoon brown sugar. Cover and simmer, stirring occasionally, 15 to 20 minutes.";
             },
                     {
                 equipment =             (
                 );
```

I need to extract the detailed step and save it but I'm not able to parse through this response. can anyone help ? this is the code I'm trying to use to save this step:

```
let recipeSumaryJson : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
let step = recipeSumaryJson["steps"]["step"]
```

Comment: Have you looked into using `Codable`? Also, you want to _decode_ not encode the response.

Comment: From the looks of the printed response, it seems that it was already decoded. Are you somehow trying to decode it twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some response and this response's value is most likely of type `Data`, so you need to **decode** it to some Swift type.

---

Since Swift 4 you can easily use `Decodable` protocol for decoding `Data` to your custom model conforming to this protocol.

So let's create simple struct for simple json

Json:

```
let data = Data("""
{
    "property": "someName"
}
""".utf8)
```

Model:

```
struct Model: Decodable {
    let property: String
}
```

---

Each property also has to be `Decodable`, so if you have different decodable struct, you can use it as property's type and you can even use it for array of this type, or for example some dictionary

Json:

```
let data = Data("""
{
    "items": [
        { "title": "name1" },
        { "title": "name2" },
        { "title": "name3" }
    ]
}
""".utf8)
```

Model:

```
struct Model: Decodable {
    let items: [Item]
}

struct Item: Decodable {
    let title: String
}
```

Do you see that pattern? So try to implement it in your case by yourself.

---

Now the last part: decoding. For decoding `Data` you can simply use [`JSONDecoder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder) and its `decode` method. Just specify type of output and pass `Data` object

Note that decoding can throw error, so you should put it to do-try-catch block

```
guard let data = response.result.value else { ... }

do {
    response.result.value!
    let models = try JSONDecoder().decode([Model].self, from: data)
} catch { print(error) }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure the JSON data that you got is valid, and then you can cast it to **[String:Any]**. After that you can simply access the value of the key. It's the most simple way to deal with JSON. There is another way which is more proper, that use Model to deal with JSON.

Answer (score 0):

// this is a program of JSON Food API calling with more labels and many more.

```
import UIKit
import AFNetworking
import SDWebImage

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource
{

    @IBOutlet var tbl_reload: UITableView!
    var getAllData = NSMutableArray()
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        CallApi()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func CallApi()
    {
        let manage = AFHTTPSessionManager()
        manage.get("https://smartfoodery.oneapp.ro/smart_food/public/api/get_restaurant/11", parameters: nil, progress: nil, success: { (Operation, response) in

            print(response!)
            if let data = response as? NSDictionary
            {
                let datas = data.value(forKey: "data") as! NSDictionary
                let restaurant_name = datas.value(forKey: "restaurant_name")
                self.title = "\(restaurant_name!)"

                let food_detail = datas.value(forKey: "food_detail") as! NSArray
                self.getAllData = NSMutableArray(array: food_detail)
                self.tbl_reload.reloadData()

            }

        }) { (Operation, Error) in
            print(Error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    //MARK:- Tableview Methods

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return getAllData.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let getData = getAllData.object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "displycell", for: indexPath) as! Customcell
        cell.lbl_name.text = (getData.value(forKey: "food_name") as! String)
        let food_image = getData.value(forKey: "food_image")
        cell.img_display.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "\(food_image!)"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
        cell.lbl_totalstock.text = "Total Stock : \(getData.value(forKey: "total_stock")!)"
        cell.lbl_foodprice.text = "Food Price :\(getData.value(forKey: "food_price")!)"
        cell.lbl_availabelstock.text = "Availabel Stock :\(getData.value(forKey: "available_stock")! )"
        cell.lbl_filtertype.text = "Filter Type : \(getData.value(forKey: "food_filter_type")!)"
        cell.lbl_availabelstock.font = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 12)!
        cell.lbl_filtertype.font = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 12)!
        cell.lbl_foodprice.font = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 12)!
        cell.lbl_totalstock.font = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 12)!
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 160.5
    }

}
```